# jquery ui autocomplete with ajax data source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use the jquery ui autocomplete feature with an ajax datasource and I just can't see what is wrong with my code.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var data = new Portalen.LitteraNumberData();

        $("#LitteraNumber").autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source : function (request, response) {
                var customerId = $("#CustomerId").val();
                return response(data.loadLitteraNumbers(customerId));
            }
        });
    });
```

and in a js file I have this:

```
Portalen.LitteraNumberData = function () { };

Portalen.LitteraNumberData.prototype = function() {

var loadLitteraNumbers = function(customerId) {
    $.get("/Orders/GetLitteraNumbers", { customerId: customerId }, function (response) {
        return response;
    });
};

return {
    loadLitteraNumbers: loadLitteraNumbers
};
}();
```

The ajax call is working, I get the correct response but the autocomplete feature just wont happen. Is LitteraNumberData  returning the wrong thing? All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = new Portalen.LitteraNumberData();
    $("#LitteraNumber").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source : function (request, response) {
            $.get("/Orders/GetLitteraNumbers", { customerId: request.term }, function (data) {
                response(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I've replaced `$("#CustomerId").val()` by `request.term`. Moreover, the function does not need to return the response.

The `$.get` function is asynchronous so you cannot put it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was really hoping to be able to encapsulate the scripts in js files and make them some what reusable in other places. I would really like to know why my approach isn't working.

Comment: Your approach isn't working because `$.get` is asynchronous. `loadLitteraNumbers()` finishes before `$.get` returns a result. I think this is the point.

Comment: What a version autocomplete with jquery ui? `Uncaught ReferenceError: Portalen is not defined`